# Datos de un TextAreaFor en C#

Tags: c#

Soy nueva trabajando con C#, tengo una tabla que trae los datos desde la base de datos, pero a esta tabla le agregue una columna de texto (TextAreaFor), necesito guardar lo que el usuario va a escribir en ese campo en una variable para enviarlo por medio de un botón al controlador que lo va a guardar en la base de datos.

Lo que necesito es que los datos que se ingresen en el campo de texto (nameObservaciones) se envien en los parametros que el boton obtiene.

Este es mi código del campo que se agregó y el botón que recibe los datos:

```
<table id="bienesSeleccionados-data-table" class="w3-table-all  w3-hoverable w3-tiny w3-responsive">
<thead>
    @*Columnas del Grid que muestran al Seleccionar Bien o Insumo*@
    <tr style="background-color:#074b83; color:white">
        <th>Id</th> @*DetallePlanAnualComprasId*@                                    
        <th>Descripción</th>
        <th>Características</th>
        <th>Cantidad Solicitada</th>
        <th>Monto Estimado</th>
        <th>Mes</th>
        <th>Total Q</th>                                    
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
       
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tbody id="detallePlanAnualComprasForm">
    @if (Model.DetallePlanAnualCompras != null)
    {
        if (Model.DetallePlanAnualCompras.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model.DetallePlanAnualCompras)
            {                    
                nameObservaciones = "DetallePlanAnualCompras[" + numItem.ToString() + "].Observaciones";
                nameDetalleId = "DetallePlanAnualCompras[" + numItem.ToString() + "].DetallePlanAnualComprasId";

                strEvento = "obtenerObservaciones(" + indexRow.ToString() + ")";
                indexRow = numItem;

                var montoestimado = "GTQ" + item.MontoEstimado.ToString();
                <tr id="@indexRow.ToString()">
                    <td class="col-md-1">
                        @Html.Hidden(nameDetalleId, item.DetallePlanAnualComprasId)
                        @if (item.PresentacionBienInsumoId > -1)
                        {
                            @item.DetallePlanAnualComprasId

                        }
                    </td>

                    <td class="col-md-1">
                        @if (item.PresentacionBienInsumoId > -1)
                        {
                            @item.DescripcionBienInsumo
                        }
                    </td>
                    
                    <td class="col-md-5">
                        @Html.Hidden(nameObservaciones, item.Observaciones)
                        @if (item.PresentacionBienInsumoId > -1)
                        {
                            if (item.Observaciones != null)
                            {
                                @Html.EditorFor(m => item.Observaciones, new { @class = "form-control-sm col-md-12", maxlength = 500 })
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Observaciones, new { @class = "form-control-sm col-md-12", maxlength = 500 })
                            }
                        }
                    </td>

                    <table>
                        <br />
                        <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-6">
                            @Html.ActionLink("Aprobar", "RevisionDeInsumo", new { DetallePlanAnualComprasId = item.DetallePlanAnualComprasId, Opcion = "Aprobado", 
                                observaciones = nameObservaciones }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })

                            @Html.ActionLink("Rechazar", "RevisionDeInsumo", new { DetallePlanAnualComprasId = item.DetallePlanAnualComprasId, Opcion = "Rechazado", 
                                observaciones = nameObservaciones }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </table>                        
                </tr>                     
            }
        }
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: yo veo un detalle, pero como tu texto no es texto, me obliga a copiar tu imagen a texto, y capaz cometo un error que no existia en tu texto... pero igual que es ese m.observaciones?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Ya trate de aclarar en lo que solicito ayuda, editando mi pregunta.